# Extracting full Attribute Name from Weka PCA

Tags: weka, pca

I am currently in the process of writing some code to analyse the [mushrooms data off UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Mushroom) using Weka. I am trying to get the values (i.e. coefficients) of the attributes, but the attribute name is truncated (indicated by the "..."), and am unable to get the full set of coefficients from the attributes.
e.g.
     @attribute -0.251a=e+0.242m=k+0.241n=k-0.224t=p+0.213f=f... numeric

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your attribute names are being truncated because of an option in the PCA filter.

```
  -A 
  Maximum number of attributes to include in 
  transformed attribute names.
  (-1 = include all, default: 5)
```

Using the following code I change the value of this option to -1 and print an attribute name from the transformed data.

```
 Instances originalTrain=...//load the training data

 PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents(); // new PCA filter
 pca.setMaximumAttributeNames(-1); //set the value to -1
 pca.setInputFormat(originalTrain);// inform filter about dataset 
 Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(originalTrain, pca);   // apply filter

 System.out.println(newData.attribute(0).name()); //look at new name
```

An example of the obviously untruncated attribute name is (scroll to view):

```
0.257stalksurfacebelowring=k+0.256stalksurfaceabovering=k+0.234ringtype=l+0.231odor=f-0.215ringtype=p-0.212stalksurfaceabovering=s+0.206sporeprintcolor=h-0.195stalksurfacebelowring=s+0.185bruises+0.18 stalkroot=b-0.176stalkcolorbelowring=w-0.175stalkcolorabovering=w-0.173odor=n-0.139sporeprintcolor=n-0.134sporeprintcolor=k+0.133habitat=p+0.133gillcolor=b+0.13 stalkcolorbelowring=b+0.13 stalkcolorabovering=b+0.129population=v+0.128stalkcolorabovering=n-0.125population=s-0.124stalkroot=e+0.121stalkcolorbelowring=n-0.119capcolor=w+0.119stalkcolorbelowring=p+0.119stalkcolorabovering=p-0.11gillspacing-0.105stalkroot=c-0.101gillcolor=n+0.094sporeprintcolor=w-0.087capshape=b-0.085gillcolor=k-0.082odor=l-0.082odor=a-0.082habitat=m+0.08 capcolor=y-0.08gillcolor=w+0.078gillcolor=h-0.076population=n-0.073habitat=g-0.072gillsize+0.068odor=y+0.068odor=s-0.067population=a-0.065capsurface=s-0.064odor=p+0.063gillcolor=g-0.059stalksurfaceabovering=f+0.057capsurface=y-0.057ringnumber=t-0.057stalksurfacebelowring=f+0.055ringnumber=o+0.051population=y-0.05habitat=u-0.048stalkcolorabovering=o-0.048stalkcolorbelowring=o+0.047veilcolor=w-0.046population=c+0.046capshape=k+0.046ringtype=e-0.046gillattachment-0.045stalkcolorabovering=g-0.045stalkcolorbelowring=g+0.043capcolor=e-0.041stalkroot=r-0.039gillcolor=u+0.039capcolor=g+0.034habitat=l-0.034veilcolor=n-0.034veilcolor=o-0.033habitat=w-0.031capcolor=p-0.031odor=c-0.031stalksurfacebelowring=y-0.031sporeprintcolor=r+0.03 capshape=f-0.029capcolor=n-0.028gillcolor=o-0.024stalkshape-0.024sporeprintcolor=o-0.024sporeprintcolor=y-0.024sporeprintcolor=b-0.024gillcolor=y-0.023gillcolor=e-0.023capcolor=b-0.023stalkcolorabovering=e-0.023stalkcolorbelowring=e-0.019gillcolor=r-0.018capshape=s-0.018sporeprintcolor=u-0.015capshape=x+0.012habitat=d+0.009gillcolor=p-0.006capsurface=g+0.005capsurface=f-0.004capshape=c+0.003stalkcolorbelowring=y-0.003stalkcolorabovering=y-0.003veilcolor=y+0.001stalksurfaceabovering=y+0.001capcolor=u+0.001capcolor=r-0.001capcolor=c+0    stalkcolorabovering=c+0    odor=m+0    ringtype=n+0    stalkcolorbelowring=c+0    ringnumber=n+0    ringtype=f
```